# How to run registry file before building a C# application?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, registry

How to run registry file before building a C# application ?

I have a C# project and I need to run a file called **omrTest_form_registry.reg** before building the project.

How can I do it ?

Comment: What is inside? Why do you need run it before each build? Sounds like http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Answer (score 1):

You can use [build event](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/810230).I dont get any result for running .reg file but you can add [.bat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/42x5kfw4.aspx) file and call it.